# Extracting lookup_value from VLOOKUP formula on MacOS

Tags: vba, macos, excel

On Windows I used the following function to extract the `lookup_value` from a `VLOOKUP` formula. However, I recently switched to macOS and the function is now incompatible.

VBA in Excel on Mac does not support regular expressions. Is there any alternative function I could use or am I out of luck?

```
Function extractFirstInt(strValue As String) As Integer
    Dim regex As New regexp
    regex.Pattern = "(\d+)"
    extractFirstInt = regex.Execute(strValue)(0).SubMatches(0)
End Function
```

Comment: [Have a look at this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27344932/regex-with-vba-excel-at-mac)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx with VBA Excel at Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27344932/regex-with-vba-excel-at-mac)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a Mac here to test, but I think this should work:

```
Function extractFirstInt(strValue As String) As Integer
    Dim codes() As Byte
    Dim n As Long
    Dim pos As Long
    Dim length As Long
    If strValue Like "*#*" Then
        codes = strValue
        length = 1
        For n = LBound(codes) To UBound(codes) Step 2
            Select Case codes(n)
                Case 48 To 57
                    If pos = 0 Then pos = n \ 2 + 1 Else length = length + 1
                Case Else
                    If pos <> 0 Then Exit For
            End Select
        Next
        extractFirstInt = CInt(Mid$(strValue, pos, length))
    End If
End Function
```