# How to highlight a substring based on a regex and turn it into Excel or HTML

Tags: html, r, excel, ms-office

I have the following data frame:

```r
dat <-  structure(list(value = c("YMNSMQEML", "FIYRHMFCV", "VLFKFDMFI", 
"KLLDRFPVA", "RVLDDFTKL")), .Names = "value", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

dat
#>       value
#> 1 YMNSMQEML
#> 2 FIYRHMFCV
#> 3 VLFKFDMFI
#> 4 KLLDRFPVA
#> 5 RVLDDFTKL
```

Given the following [regex pattern](https://regex101.com/r/36Z2WX/1) `L.{2}[FR]` 
I would like to create an Excel where the substring is highlighted bold.

[image]

How can I achieve that?

---

**UPDATE**
Using LIKE operator:

```r
Option Explicit
Sub boldSubString_LIKE_OPERATOR()
    Dim R As Range, C As Range
    Dim MC As Object
    Set R = Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))

    For Each C In R
        C.Font.Bold = False
        If C.Text Like "L**F" Then
            Set MC = .Execute(C.Text)
            C.Characters(MC(0).firstindex + 1, MC(0).Length).Font.Bold = True
        End If
    Next C

End Sub
```

It  breaks at `Set MC = .Execute(C.Text)`, gives Compile Error Invalid or Unqualified Reference.

Comment: You can format entire cells using several packages (my favorite is `openxlsx`), but as far as I know, there is no way to format selected content within a cell.

Comment: convert your text to HTML and try this https://gist.github.com/FayazK/b48227320d4bc042b80943bc5c4daf44

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this in Excel, you access the `Characters` property of the `Range` object:  (and the contents needs to be an actual string; not a formula that returns a string)

```
Option Explicit
Sub boldSubString()
    Dim R As Range, C As Range
    Dim RE As Object, MC As Object
    Const sPat As String = "L.{2}[FR]"

'Range to be processed
Set R = Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))

'Initialize Regex engine
'Could use early binding if desireable
Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With RE
    .Global = False
    .ignorecase = True
    .Pattern = sPat

    For Each C In R
        C.Font.Bold = False
        If .test(C.Text) Then
            Set MC = .Execute(C.Text)
            C.Characters(MC(0).firstindex + 1, MC(0).Length).Font.Bold = True
        End If
    Next C
End With

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: this is really great. I'm new to VB. What step should I do in Microsoft Excel to run your code? (i.e. which button to click, enter the code etc...)

Comment: You should work through some online VBA tutorials. But, to enter this Macro (Sub), `alt-F11` opens the Visual Basic Editor.
Ensure your project is highlighted in the Project Explorer window.
Then, from the top menu, select `Insert/Module` and
paste the code into the window that opens.

To use this Macro (Sub), `alt-F8` opens the macro dialog box. Select the macro by name, and **`RUN`**.

Comment: I tried your code but it give me: Run-time error 429. ActiveX component can't create object.

Comment: @scamander Would you care to share which line shows the error?  What version of Excel?  What OS?

Comment: @RonResenfeld Thank you for your reply. This is the related post that shows my versio of Excel.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54509273/how-to-enable-regex-engine-in-microsoft-excel-visual-basic?noredirect=1#comment95822143_54509273
Does that mean I can't run your code on Mac?

Comment: @scamander that is correct.  See [Regex with VBA Excel at MAC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27344932/regex-with-vba-excel-at-mac)

Comment: the code breaks in this line: `Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")`

Comment: @scamander You can solve this problem without using Regular Expressions. Use the `Like` operator with wild cards, and step through the lines that match the pattern to find the start.

Comment: but with Like operator I still have to *manually* highlight every matching region with bold right?

Comment: @scamander What makes you think that?  The code I provided doesn't require that.  Substituting string functions for the regex should not require that either.

Comment: please see my update in this post. I use "LIKE" operator but doesn't work. Your insight is greatly appreciated.

Comment: @scamander You are using the wrong expression for `Like` to match your regex pattern.  In addition, you are still using methods that require the VBA Regex reference, which you don't have.  I suggest you post a new question with your efforts, results and problems; and also consider either familiarizing yourself more with VBA, investigating the add-in mentioned in the duplicate to your other question, or using a tool with which you have more familiarity.

Answer (score 4):

Since you mentioned HTML as well, you may generate an Rmarkdown HTML
document and surround the pattern by the `<b></b>` tags.
A minimal example using `str_replace` function from the `stringr` package:

````
---
output:
  html_document: default
title: "Pattern"
---


```{r echo = FALSE}
library(stringr)

## your data
dat <-  structure(list(value = c("YMNSMQEML", "FIYRHMFCV", "VLFKFDMFI",
"KLLDRFPVA", "RVLDDFTKL")), .Names = "value", row.names = c(NA,
-5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))


pattern <- "(L.{2}[FR])" # in brackets to reuse it in str_replace as \1
## surround \1 group with the bold tag
dat$value <-  str_replace(dat$value, pattern, "<b>\\1</b>")

knitr::kable(dat)
```
````

[image: click here to see the result]