# CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp") Run-time error '429'

Tags: excel, vba

I've just started studying **Excel VBA with Mac**. When I executed the following macro, run-time error occurred. Could anyone help me out?

**Here is my code:**

```
Sub macro()
  Dim regex As Object, matchList As Object
  Dim str As String, patternStr As String
  str = "0123-4567"
  patternStr = "\d+"
  'patternStr = "¥d+"
  
  Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
  With regex
      .Global = True
      .Pattern = patternStr
      Set matchList = .Execute(str)
  End With
End Sub
```

**Here is the error message:**

```
Run-time error '429':
ActiveX component can't create object
```

Comment: That can't work on Mac - ActiveX is a Windows-only thing.

Comment: My computer works fine. I use windows.

Comment: @Tim Williams Does that mean regular expressions are not available on Mac?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27344932/regex-with-excel-vba-on-mac

Comment: @Tim Williams Thank you for the link. I'm just coding as the textbook says now. I'll skip a chapter about RegExp. I'm going to buy PC. The information that regular expressions are not available on Mac is so helpful. Thank you.

Comment: You would definitely find you're limited using VBA on Mac compared to Windows.  A lot of things you'd find online for VBA would end up being Windows-only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActiveX is for only Windows, which means regular expressions are not officially available on Mac. It needs to download third-party libraries to enable regular expressions work on Mac.

Thank you for your help, Tim Williams.